# solr schema synonym issue

Tags: search, solr, lucene, multilingual

i use this configuration to search data contain both English products and its equivalent in Chinese.

```
        <fieldType name="text_synm" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer type="index">

        <tokenizer class="solr.CJKTokenizerFactory"/>

            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonym.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
              <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnNumerics="1" />
               <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

        </analyzer>

        <analyzer type="query">

            <tokenizer class="solr.CJKTokenizerFactory"/>

              <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonym.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
              <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnNumerics="1" />
               <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

but when i search in chinese in solr admin it give me no result

i tried to use

```
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
```

instead of

```
<tokenizer class="solr.CJKTokenizerFactory"/>
```

but there is no result
i make sure that  that the synonym.txt is utf-8 encode

any clue here?

Comment: i guess you need to edit your post... it is not clear what kinda Tokenizer factory you have used as you typed the same thing twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think any way i should edit the apach/conf/server.xml and add this

```
URIEncoding="UTF-8" useBodyEncodingForURI = "false"
```

to the connector tag to be for example

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" useBodyEncodingForURI = "false" />
```

also in the

```
 <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443">
```

i should add this

```
URIEncoding="UTF-8"
```

any way it did not work in my case may be cause my synonym.txt file is mixed between Chinese and english i hope some one find more advanced answer.